# Prove that $\mathcal{U}$ is not a topology on $\mathbb{R}

Tags: general-topology

***A first course in algebraic topology*** by C. Kosniowski asks us to prove that $\mathcal{U}=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(a,b);a,b\in \mathbb{R},a<b\}$ is NOT a topology.  I've been trying to set a family of sub sets from this like $\{(a_{j},b_{j});a_{j},b_{j}\in \mathbb{R}, j\in J\}$.

Is it ok to say the following?:

$\cup_{j\in J}(a_{j},b_{j})=(min\{a_{j};j\in J\},max\{b_{j};j\in J\})$ which the largest interval and is contained on $\mathbb{R}$?

Can I use that to prove that $\mathcal{U}$ is NOT a topology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* Before jumping to the general case of trying to describe an arbitrary union of intervals, think about a simple case, like $(0,1)\cup (2,3)$...

Comment: But that tells me that $\mathcal{U}$ is a topology, right?

Comment: $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$ are in $\mathcal{U}$. A topology is closed under unions, so $(0,1)\cup (2,3)$ should be in $\mathcal{U}$. Is it?

Comment: That union is going to be $(0,3)$ isn´t it? and that's in $\mathcal{U}$, isn't it?

Comment: Really? $1.5\in (0,1)\cup (2,3)$? @JoshuaLópezAraiza

Comment: And what about $1$ and $2$? These are in $(0,3)$. Are they in $(0,1)\cup (2,3)$?

Comment: You're right, I can see that now,and no, $1.5 \notin (0,1)\cup (2,3)$